# Como eu garanto números únicos em uma lista de listas?

Tags: python, array, lista, for, random

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer uma cartela de bingo 5x5, usando random para gerar os valores, no entanto não pode haver números iguais. Tentei fazer dessa forma mas ainda surge números iguais:

```
import random as rd
cart1 = []

for i in range(0, 5):
    cart1.append([])

for l in range(0, 5):
    for c in range(0, 5):
        var = rd.randint(0, 99)

        if var not in cart1:
            cart1[l].append(var)

print("\n")
print("A cartela 1 é:")
for l in range(0, 5):
    for c in range(0, 5):
        print(f"[{cart1[l][c]:^5}]", end="")

    print()
```

Um dos resultados:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
lista = random.sample(range(100),10)
```

Esse comando gera uma lista de 10 números variando de 0 a 99. Com isso você pode organizar da forma que achar melhor.

Se você quiser organizar em matriz, eu recomendo usar numpy array.

Por exemplo:

```
import random
lista = random.sample(range(100),25)
lista = np.array(lista)
lista = np.reshape(lista, (5, 5))
```

*resultado:*

```
array([[29, 85,  6, 40, 14],
       [78,  2, 77, 41, 46],
       [ 9, 52, 68, 19, 97],
       [65, 90, 75, 93, 50],
       [31,  4, 27, 55, 10]])
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!